# Adding inputs to a `tf.data.generator` in tensorflow.js

Tags: javascript, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to create a data generator, which I verified was working by itself in pure js. TFJS documentation for it is here, with two examples:
https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#data.generator

I'd like to use a `tf.data.generator` as this datasets requires elaborate preprocessing. A minimal example is as follows:

```js
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');
class dataGeneratorGenerator {
    constructor(test) {
        this.test = test
    }
    * dataGenerator() {
        let len = this.test.length
        let idx = 0
        while (idx < len) {
            idx++
            console.log(idx)
            yield this.test[idx]
        }
    }
}
let dgg = new dataGeneratorGenerator(['hi', 'hi2', 'hi3'])
let trainDs = tf.data.generator(dgg.dataGenerator);
trainDs.forEachAsync(e => console.log(e));
```

The error is as follows:

```
TypeError: Error thrown while iterating through a dataset: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined
```

Iterating through our datagenerator in pure javascript works:

```js
let dgg = new dataGeneratorGenerator(['hi', 'hi2', 'hi3'])
let dg = dgg.dataGenerator()
console.log(dgg.next())
console.log(dgg.next())
console.log(dgg.next())
```

My understanding is that we are only passing `dataGenerator` into `tf.data.generator` instead of the entire class. Then, how is it possible to input variables into `tf.data.generator`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can simply use an arrow function.

```js
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');

function* dataGenerator(test) {
    let len = test.length
    let idx = 0
    while (idx < len) {
        idx++
        console.log(idx)
    }
}

let trainDs = tf.data.generator(() => dataGenerator(['hi', 'hi2', 'hi3']));

trainDs.forEachAsync(e => console.log(e));
```